# Is it possible to save Sub-Folds in Sublime? Bufferscroll doesn't seem to do it

Tags: sublimetext3

Using Bufferscroll for sublime is great in that it saves all my folds between saves. The issue I'm having is that I have many subfolds, and everytime i hide and then expand a parent-fold, all the subfolds are re-expanded. Is there a way to just fold/unfold the parent but keep all the children in their last state until explicitly unfolded?

@PatatjeNL  thanks for the response, but i think that either i'm still doing something wrong, or i may not have fully explained the question. allow me to share an example:

```
def foo():
    if a == b:
        bar(a)
        bar(b)
        return 1
    if c==d:
        bar(c)
        bar(d)
        return 2
```

ok.. so with the above, i could fold on the def foo() line (1), the if a==b: line (2), or the if c==d: line (3). If i fold (2) and (3), all is good. I can then fold (1). But if i *then* UNfold 1, (2) and (3) are no longer folded. Everything that is contained by (1) unfolds, which is what i'm trying to keep in state.

i did try re-installing a few times,and certainly i may be continuing to have a technical issue in that regard, but i thought i'd lay it out this way just to make sure we were on the same wavelength.

thanks again for the attention!!

Comment: The sounds like a awesome feature. As I'm wondering about this aswell, I've created an issue on the BufferScroll GitHub page. You may read more about it here: https://github.com/SublimeText/BufferScroll/issues/12

Answer (score -1):

Well, it seems that BufferScroll actually did implement this feature. Somehow I didn't get it working before, which lead me to believe that it was not implemented - I've just tried it and it actually works.

According to a collaborator's answer at the [issue report at the BufferScroll GitHub page](http://github.com/SublimeText/BufferScroll/issues/12), this feature was implemented.

When the saving of the folded code does not work, you could try reinstalling the BufferScroll package.

Comment: No, subfolds are not implemented.